# space and hash ( #) causing an error as a coffeescript regex?

Tags: regex, parsing, coffeescript, runtime-error

The simplest way to express this question is with a small example in the repl:

```
coffee> "hello".split(/: #/) #this is fine
[ 'hello' ]
coffee> "hello".split(/\s#/) #all good here too
[ 'hello' ]
coffee> "hello".split(/ #/)  #wtf??
[stdin]:1:20: error: missing )
"hello".split(/ #/)
```

Why does the last regex not work? from playing around a bit it seems that there will be an error for any regex matching `^ +.*#.*$` Note, that is a space at the start of the regex. (e.g. `/  foo#bar/` but not `/foo bar#baz/`).

Is this a bug in the parser?

(running `CoffeeScript version 1.7.1` on `Arch Linux`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the coffee lexer is trying to figure out if the first `/` is the division operator or a start of a regex, and guesses wrong in that case. [Here](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/lexer.html#section-19)) is the relevant code. I am not sure if that is a bug.

If you put that in a file:

```
"hallo".match / #/
  1
```

and use `coffee -p` you'll see that it is parsed as the division operator.
If you add an non-capturing group at the beginning, you'll get an Expression that is (almost, since it does take up more space and neglegible regex-compilation time) equivalent to the one you're aiming for:

```
"hall #o".match /(?:) #/
```

**Edit:**

As [mu is to short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) has pointed out, it might be easier to just put a backslash in front of the space.

```
"hall #o".match /\ #/
```

Comment: I'd probably go with `/\ #/`, backslash is the usual [do what I want kludge](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9492992/479863).

Comment: Ahhh, I had been trying to do `/ \#/` to try and get it to work (which doesn't). Good point about escaping the space instead. Do we think that it's a bug? Should I be opening an issue on github? Thanks again.

Comment: can you star issues on github? I just searched for it – [it exists as an issue since March](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3410).