# How do I output a block text in coffeescript with spaces BEFORE everything

Tags: string, coffeescript

```
redditFunny = """
                                     TEST TEST
"""
console.log redditFunny
```

compiles into

```
var redditFunny;

redditFunny = "TEST TEST";

console.log(redditFunny);
```

I just want to output it as is

Answer (score 2):

From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#strings):

> Block strings can be used to hold formatted or indentation-sensitive text (or, if you just don't feel like escaping quotes and apostrophes). **The indentation level that begins the block is maintained throughout**, so you can keep it all aligned with the body of your code.

Emphasis mine. The example they give is that this CoffeeScript:

```
html = """
       <strong>
         cup of coffeescript
       </strong>
       """
```

becomes this JavaScript:

```
html = "<strong>\n  cup of coffeescript\n</strong>";
```

Note that the "inner" indentation is preserved while the "outer" indentation is removed.

The trick is to make CoffeeScript think you have a zero length "outer" indentation so that it will strip off zero leading spaces. Something like this chicanery for example:

```
s = """
\ this
 is indented
"""
```

will become this JavaScript:

```
s = "\ this\n is indented"
//   ^^      ^
```

Note that `'\ '` is a complicated way of writing `' '` because an escaped space is just a space.

You could also use the fact that `\u0020` is the Unicode escape for a space and say:

```
s = """
\u0020this
 is indented
"""
```

to achieve the same output.

This seems a bit dodgy and fragile to me but similar things are the [recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494598/479863) to deal with leading `#`s in block regexes so this should be pretty safe.

I would probably avoid all this cleverness and write a little indenting function that split a string on `'\n'` and pasted it back together with leading indentation so that I could say:

```
indent(some_string_with_newlines, '           ')
```

to indent the block with eleven spaces.

Comment: yeah it just seems really silly that there isn't a way to write a string without the indentation check. At the time of writing this I couldn't bring myself to write a function. guess that is the only way :(